# AlertDialog throwing runtime error

Tags: android, runtime, android-alertdialog, android-windowmanager

Recently I have created inner tabs via TabHost - an activity that was TabActivity3 is now TabActivity4, when testing everything looks good. But when clicking one of the buttons (which call AlertDialog) it throws this error, bare in mind this is fine if the code is at TabActivity3, but when moved to an inner Tab (TabActivity4) this happens.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@2f93937 is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:849)
                                                             at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:337)
                                                             at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
                                                             at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:350)
                                                             at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3782)
                                                             at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3731)
                                                             at com.example.tabdemo.Tab4Activity$2.onClick(Tab4Activity.java:100)
                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The code

```
public class Tab4Activity extends Activity
{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab4);

         eta =(Button)findViewById(R.id.etaButton);

        eta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });
}
}
```

I think the answer may be with the getActivity() method - but unsure how to implement.

Comment: Stack Trace and code you posted is not helpful.

Comment: Post entire stack trace and the method `showDialog`

Comment: @Klevi01 updated.

Comment: @AbhishekJain there is no method showDialog - I can only assume it comes from import android.app.AlertDialog; - as I said this ran 100% when Tab3Activity - problems only occurred when moving to a inner tab

Comment: @MarkJames Tab4Activity  code is not clear. Anyway [`showDialog()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog(int)) is depreceted.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to work round this @Klev01